# Sending commands through GPIB via Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, gpib

I have this network analyzer and need to send commands to it via Excel VBA and GPIB. I have the GPIB and other hardware set up just fine, but I do not know how to simply send commands through the GPIB to the analyzer. I have considerable programming experience but I am brand new to VBA. After *hours* searching through hardware documentation and VBA tutorials my spirit is slowly dying. I believe I need to add the correct References in VBA (Tools -> References) but when I try to run sample code given by the documentation ("Call viOpenDefaultRM(defrm)") I get an error that the Sub or function is not defined.

Any help is very much appreciated. I am working as an engineer and somehow get thrown into tasks that require lots of coding.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using a VISA library (which would delegate to a GPIB library when you open a GPIB resource). So, you should have a VISA32.bas from your VISA vendor that you can at least copy portions of into your VBA project.

Or use VISA-COM if your VISA vendor provides it and use Tools -> References for it.

Answer (score 0):

To reference functions in an external DLL, you need to `Declare` them in a module in the Excel file.  The declaration identifies the path to the external library, the entry point, the external function's parameters and return value types.

In your specific case, the `Declare` might look something like:

```
Public Declare Sub viOpenDefaultRM Lib "gpib_functions.dll" (defrm as String)
```

You'd need to include the path to the library file "gpib_functions.dll" in your %PATH% system variable, or else explicitly list the full path in the `Declare`.

See '[Calling DLL Functions and Commands from VBA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687915(v=office.15).aspx#sectionSection0)' for more info.